# R and S3 generic functions

Tags: r

I am having trouble creating an S3 print method for a function I have.

Within the function I have two variables, one returns a single number, and the other returns a data frame with multiple rows and multiple columns.

Within my function I have the following:

```
rate = A/B
kout = list(rate, C)
class(kout) = 'kfoldOut'
return(kout)
```

in the above A and B are numeric and C is a data.frame with 2 rows and 50 columns. I then create my print method as follows.

```
print.kfoldOut = function(x) {
cat("Rate:", x$rate)
print(x$C)
}
```

When I run my function e.g.

```
z = func(x,y)
```

and then

```
print(z)
```

I get `Rate: NULL`

I can return `Rate` and `C` directly within my function and everything looks good, but cannot get the print method working.

EDIT: The output of `dput(z)`, note I have removed values for ease of view.

`structure(list(0.312169312169312, structure(list(C = c(0, 
0), X1 = c(1, 0), X2 = c(1, 0), .... X18.9 = c(1, 0), X19.8 = c(0, 0)), .Names = c("C", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", .... "X19.8"), row.names = c("trueV", "testing_rd2"
), class = "data.frame")), class = "kfoldOut")`

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(z)` to your question.

Comment: In your output of `dput(z)`, there appears to be no column named `rate`. As such, looking for `x$rate` would have to return `NULL`. EDIT: Maybe that already is your problem. If not, please provide a minimal working example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: sorry, rate is represented by the 0.312169... as this is calculated in my function and assigned to rate. Like wise, my function assigned the data.frame to C containing two rows and multiple columns.